# How to count and mark all counted objects in this image

Tags: image-processing

I need some help on image processing in Mathematica (I have unsuccesfully tried with OpenCV).

I have an image:

[image]

and I need to count all objects in this image and mark them.

The perfect result would look like this:

[image]

Is this possible? How?

Thank you all for your help. Alternative question:
Is there a solution how to get rid of all the connections between objects without changing the rest of the image: [image]

Thank you in advance!
Lauris

Comment: OpenCV ? Are you sure this question is about Wolfram *Mathematica* ?

Comment: I failed to solve this by using OpenCV - I do not know if this possible using Wolfram Mathematica!

Comment: I have not done anything (produced code) yet using Wolfram Mathematica. It was said to me that our University have Wolfram Mathematica so I just wanted to know if this possible and then start to dig in code.

Comment: Wow! `Binarize[img, 0]` for a nice surprise! It was there all along!

Comment: Yes, this definitely looks like the distance transform of a binary image. Why not provide the original binary image in the first place?

Comment: These are medical data - we do not have in university source images :(

Answer (score 5):

You can play with the binarization value to tweak the results:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWNaK.png"]; 
MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img, 0.4]] // Colorize
```

[image]

You can then calculate the positions, means, sizes, etc of the components using `ComponentMeasurements` as in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66606/1783) answer.

As for your second question, about removing the links between objects, the straightforward approach here is `Erosion`. For instance

```
Erosion[img, 5]
```

nicely removes the bulk of the links. Again, you will want to play with the erosion parameter (in this case 5) for best effect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What would be your guess of percentage of objects which I will be able to count and mark by this approach?

Comment: There are two kinds of errors that might happen: you might miss a component that does exist or you might find an extra one (that doesn't really exist). You can balance these two possible kinds of errors, but never eliminate them completely.

Comment: That is clear! I am planning to analyse medical data. Allowed error is plus/minus 3%. Currently I have error of 15% or more :(

Answer (score 4):

Here's a set of functions, drawn mostly from [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) and a portion of [this screencast](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/introducingmathematica7/).  It is not a perfect answer at this point; the major problem being the small tendrils that link features together.  It is possible that some type of filter with a `DiskMatrix` mask will lead you to a better result, but for the moment, I suspect there's a lot to wade through here.

```
seimg = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWNaK.png"];
i = GaussianFilter[FillingTransform[seimg], 15];
b = Binarize[i];
d = DistanceTransform[b, Padding -> 0];
m = MaxDetect[ImageAdjust[d, 0.2]];
w = WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[b, 3], m, Method -> "Rainfall"];
s = SelectComponents[w, "Count", 20 < # < 10000 &];
ms = ComponentMeasurements[
   s, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "Label"}];
Show[seimg, 
 Graphics[{Blue, Circle @@ # & /@ (ms[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]]), 
   MapThread[Text, {ms[[All, 2, 3]], ms[[All, 2, 1]]}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution how to get rid of all the connections between objects without changing the rest of the image? I suspect that by doing this and afterwards using DiskMatrix it could improve results!